# jquery multiple div selection at a time

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="user_clicked" id="2"></div>
<div class="user_clicked" id="3"></div>
<div class="user_clicked" id="4"></div>
```

As you can see all the divs have same class with different id..

My requirement is that the user can select multiple divs at a time to get the result. How this can be done in jquery?

Comment: _"the user can select multiple divs at a time to get the result"_ - To get _what_ result? Do you mean you want to let the user click on the divs and have something happen to whichever ones they've clicked? And you would like some JS/jQuery code to figure out what they've clicked on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this by

```
 $(".user_clicked")
```

it will select all div have class `user_clicked`

also you select multiple like

```
$('selector1, selector2, selectorN')
```

if you want to select different  selector

Comment: OP's requirement is that "the _user_ can select multiple divs" - I'm not clear what that means exactly, but...

Answer (score 3):

You can select a common property of each, like `$('.user_clicked')`, or if you want to select just the ID 1 and 2 `$('#div1, #div2')` (you aren't allowed to start an HTML name or ID with a number, so in this example it would be `id="div1"` and `id="div2"`)

If you wanted to iterate through them, you can use `each()`:

```
$('.user_clicked').each(function(){ }); // select all with class user_clicked
$('#div1, #div2').each(function(){ });  // select with IDs div1 and div2
```

Comment: OP's rather vague requirement is that "the _user_ can select multiple divs" - I would've though that meant responding to some event so that the divs are _visibly_ selected (as compared to "select" in the sense of a CSS or jQuery "selector"). By the way, html5 allows `id` attributes to start with or be made up entirely of digits.